# Laravel - Mock DB Expression

Tags: php, laravel, mocking

How would I mock the following where clause?

`->where(DB::raw('NOW()'), '<', DB::raw('(ue.accepted_at + INTERVAL 1 YEAR)'))`

This is what the test looks like:

```
$mockQueryBuilder
    ->shouldReceive('select')->twice()->andReturnSelf()
    ->shouldReceive('from')->once()->andReturnSelf()
    ->shouldReceive('join')->twice()->andReturnSelf()
    ->shouldReceive('where')->with('ue.user_id', $user->id)->once()->andReturnSelf()
    ->shouldReceive('where')->with('e.type_id', 1)->once()->andReturnSelf()
    ->shouldReceive('where')->with(function (\Closure $closure) {})->andReturnSelf() // This should be testing the raw expression
    ->shouldReceive('whereNull')->with('e.deleted_at')->once()->andReturnSelf()
    ->shouldReceive('whereNotNull')->with('e.published_at')->once()->andReturnSelf();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with matching with objects, the best approach is writing custom matchers, due to how equality works on objects, as an example `DB::raw('1') !== DB::raw('1')`.

A `Matcher` to work with db raw would look something like this.

```
use Mockery\Matcher\MatcherAbstract;

class DBRawMatcher extends MatcherAbstract
{
    /** @var string */
    private $expression;

    public function __construct(string $expression) {
        $this->expression = $expression;
    }

    public function match(&$actual) {
        // $actual is of type Expression
        return $actual->getValue() === $this->expression;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'DBRawMatcher';
    }
}
```

Simply saving your DB raw input into the class and unpacking the expression that the db raw returns. Then compares that it is the same.

Now you could create your mocking logic.

```
->shouldReceive('where')->once()->with(
    new DBRawMatcher('NOW()'),
    '>',
    new DBRawMatcher('(ue.accepted_at + INTERVAL 1 YEAR)')
)->andReturnSelf()
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll check this out. Thx.

Comment: Did it help on your mocking?

Comment: It was an interesting approach... I ended up using `DB::spy()` and replacing the expressions with dates, which seemed to resolve the issue. I will post it as an answer. Upvoted this.